# Problem with vecLib when trying to run a node.js server. 

Tags: xcode, debugging, macos, node.js

I receive this error when trying to run a node.js server.

I recently migrated data from an old mbp to a new mbp, and it wasn't completely smooth. I had to reinstall xcode after the migration but I don't know if it is at all related.

Here is the error in full...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: vecLib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libLAPACK.dylib provides version 0.0.0
Trace/BPT trap
```

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up reinstalling OSX and all libraries. Seemed to be a problem with a migration of installs from a 32-bit systems to a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this would be happening, try stopping into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and asking people questions :)

Comment: Ended up reinstalling OSX and all libraries. Seemed to be a problem with a migration of installs from a 32-bit systems to a 64-bit system.